# How do I ensure an external disk mounts before certain apps launch at startup?

Tags: ssd, mount, startup, dropbox

I have an SSD connected to my iMac via USB, and I use it to store, among other things, my Dropbox folder, which is too large for my built-in storage.

This generally works well, but sometimes (often) when I restart my computer, Dropbox pops up a warning that it can't find the Dropbox folder, presumably because the SSD hadn't mounted yet when the app launched and checked for its data.

By the time I can interact with the system, the disk *is* mounted... so I don't think this is a problem with the disk, I think it's a timing issue.

Is there any way to have apps launch at startup, but have them *wait* for an event, like a disk being mounted?

Comment: Have you looked at 'Delay Start' in the App Store?

Comment: The biggest problem you’re going to have here is the USB bus; and there are two issues. First, is when the. USB bus gets initialized. Before you can mount a USB disk, the USB must be up and running. Secondly, the BUS often gets reset during boot. I know this because I have a USB barcode scanner attached and it makes an audible tone when initialized and during a boot, it will initialize *twice,* meaning whatever was connected got disconnected momentarily.  This is why USB mounts don’t happen until late in the process. I would look at a different interface; maybe Thunderbolt?

Comment: Is the drive encrypted? Formatting it to APFS may help speed up unlocking the encryption.

Comment: I have the same issue on my M1 Mac Mini and encrypted, Thunderbolt-connected external SSD.